# Cannot display text in a label ClientID

Tags: javascript, c#

I am building a web application using asp.net c#. In my HTML code, I've included Javascript that display text to one of my textbox. However, when I am trying to display text to my label, it isn't working. I am not sure why.

Here is my code

```
document.getElementById('<%=this.txtEmployee.ClientID %>').value = name;
document.getElementById('<%=this.lblDepartment.ClientID %>').value = dept;
document.getElementById('<%=this.txtSupervisorId.ClientID %>').value = id;
```

Both the txtEmployee and txtSupervisorId works well because they are text box. But lblDepartment doesn't work (it is a label). Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label` doesn't have any value property, you need to set **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** or **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**

```
document.getElementById('<%=this.txtSupervisorId.ClientID %>').textContent = id;
```

---

**DEMO :**

```js
document.getElementById('label').textContent = 'hello';
```

```html
<label id="label">hi</label>
```

Comment: @DragonBorn : glad to help you :)